# Correct loading order jQuery, Bootstrap and select2 .js files

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, loading, jquery-select2

I would like to ask if there is a specific loading order in your web pages that should be used for the jQuery, Bootstrap and Select2 JavaScript files in order to avoid any potential errors and if there should be one what would be the most appropriate one.

Comment: jQuery first, always. The other two do not depend on each other so can be in any order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will always need to load `jQuery` **before** `bootstrap` or **any** other plugins that rely on it.

I like to order my links/references as JavaScript first, css second and ensure that each reference is ordered by their respective plugin but thats just my own personal preference.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for the useful answer.